# Solar Power for Computer Build

Tags: solar-panels

I am going to be trying to power my currently in progress computer build with solar power. I'm not for sure what I should be looking for power wise. I have a 1000 watt power supply that apparently is 6.5 amps I think. I'm not for sure if I should find a 6 or 7 amp solar panel or if I should go for a combination of solar panels to get 1000 watts out of it and get some kind of transformer to take the amps down or volts so it won't blow up my hole system or overload it with power. If I am wrong on any of this please correct me.

Comment: As the other guy said, you might be biting off more than you can chew.  Seriously, start off with a Raspberry Pi which runs off 5V DC and draws miniscule watts before jumping into bigger loads.

Comment: At the very least you'll need to figure out how to power it atnight or when cloudy ... though you might be able to get away with using a laptop's battery as a pseudo-UPS. I agree with others that the first step id to define your requirements MUCH more precisely,  in terms of what the machine needs, how long you want to run it every day and under what powrr management settings (worst case), whether you care about portability, whether you care about cost efficiency (a small solar setup may not pay for itself; a house-sized system can)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pc power electronics, not Home Improvement. (Unless it's changed to be about installing solar panels on a home, in which case it's probably a duplicate.) I'd suggest trying tne Electronics area

Comment: Just because you have a 1000 watt power supply does not mean that your system will draw 1000 watts. Best to measure your system at full load (cpu = 100% usage) to see how much power it actually draws. For example, I have a 650 watt power supply but my system only pulls about 120 watts, if that, at full load. When idle it probably pulls 60 watts.

Comment: Also voting to close, but in case anyone stumbles across this: If you are doing this, look at powering the computer system via DC as opposed to AC (search term "DC-DC power supply").

Answer (score 3):

Skip it, seriously. I don't know what your motivation for this is, but you need to learn just a wee tad more before you bite it off.

If it's (sounds like not) a remote-off-grid solar powered computer, you start with making it efficient, and then then address the power supply (probably not a wall-plug-in-type), days of running without sun, batteries, charge controllers, etc...

If you are on-grid but have vague greenish feelings that somehow have not impacted your choice of power supply/motherboard, just set up a small (or large) grid-tie system and plug the computer into the grid. That will be adequately complicated for you to start learning about.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd go for a laptop. That has a built-in UPS, and has an easy-to-reach DC input, so you don't need to go DC->120V AC->DC again. (This would lower the complexity of the build, reduce losses from the conversion, and ensure that you don't have to screw around with 120V AC.) The laptop power brick will specify the expected output, so you know exactly what voltage/amperage is expected by the laptop. In addition, laptops generally have lower power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

your solar system needs to provide enough wattage at the proper voltage if you have the correct voltage it is ok to have more wattage avaiable. two much voltage will dammage your system two little it wont turn on.

Answer (score 1):

I say research your idea and go for it. Some of the best innovations came about from people trying what others claimed to be impossible. Try it, if you have the inclination and resources what's the harm? Keep me posted. The one feasible way that I know of to power a desk top(?) computer with solar energy is an indirect method that you already are aware of. You can power a computer with a back up power source. Usually in the form of an external battery. Along with the battery you will need to convert the Direct Current to an Alternating Current (DC to AC). This is accomplished with a convertor. Lastly, the P.V. panel is installed to charge the battery. The amount of components to do this can get costly. The size of the PSU in your computer and the length of time it will be used for will determine the size and cost of the P.V panel, the battery (-ies) and the convertor. There are emergency back-up units that have been on the open market for awhile now. They are mostly used in situations where not losing data is critical. They are only meant to provide power for a short time, though.

Comment: Nobody claimed it was impossible. Fiscally non-viable and several steps of self-education beyond where Dacota seems to be at present; but not at all impossible.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't pointing fingers. My "impossible" sentence was meant to be a general term and not directed at any ones answer. Peace-out.